# A semigroup is $\mathcal{R}$-unipotent if and only if its idempotents form a left normal band?

Tags: abstract-algebra, semigroups

A semigroup $S$ is *$\mathcal{R}$-unipotent* if its regular and  $efe=ef$ for any idempotents $e,f$ in S.

I want to show that if $S$ is regular then $S$ is $\mathcal{R}$-unipotent
 if and only if its idempotents form a *left normal band*, that is,    $gfe=gef$ for any idempotents in $e,f,g$ of $S$.

If $S$ is regular and its idempotents form a left normal band then, for any $e,f,g$ idempotents of $S$ we have

$$gfe=gef.$$ In particular, $$efe=eef=ef. $$

Reciprocally , let's assume $S$ is $\mathcal{R}$-unipotent. Let $e,f,g$ be idempotents of $S$. Then
  $$gfe=gfef=gf(gef) $$ and $$gef=gefe=ge(gfe). $$  Therefore $gfe \mathrel{\mathcal{L}}gef$.  If I managed to show $gfe \mathrel{\mathcal{R}}gef$ since in a $\mathcal{R}$-unipotent semigroup each $\mathcal{R}$-class only has one idempotent I could conclude $gef=gfe.$ Any hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Counterexample**. Take the 5-element idempotent monoid $M = \{1, a, b, ab, ba\}$ presented by $aba = ab$ and $bab = ba$. Then $efe = ef$ for all $e, f \in M$, but the identity $gef = gfe$ fails if you take $g = 1$, $e = a$ and $f = b$.

Comment: What do you mean by "right normal band instead"?

Comment: It is a very bad idea to change your question. Please put back your original question so that the answers correspond to the question. If you have another question, post it separately.

Comment: I'll. Thanks for the feedback.